# Docker port doesn't seem exposed on macOS

Tags: macos, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-machine

I try to run a container which has a djangorestframework server running, with the following command:

```
docker run --tty --interactive --detach \
  --publish "$PUBLISH" \
  --name $NAME \
  --volume "$PWD:/home/gateway/project" \
  gateway
```

where $PUBLISH == "8000:8000"

Unfortunately, when I try to load a page in my browser, it seems that the port is not forwarded.

I nmaped from inside the running container, the port 8000 is open on 127.0.0.1
I nmaped the virtual machine, the port is closed. I don't know why.

The docker logs show that the service is running, but did not receive any request. Yes, it seems obvious since the host port is closed.

Oh, and `docker ps` shows

```
0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
```

on the PORTS column

What am I doing wrong, how can I access my page?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Try using `-p 8000:8000` like this:

```
docker run --tty --interactive --detach \
--publish "$PUBLISH" \
--name $NAME \
--volume "$PWD:/home/gateway/project" \
-p 8000:8000
gateway
```

Then you can simply check using netcat with

```
nc -vz 127.0.0.1 8000
```

> With the exception of the EXPOSE directive, an image developer hasn’t got much control over networking. The EXPOSE instruction defines the initial incoming ports that provide services. These ports are available to processes inside the container. An operator can use the --expose option to add to the exposed ports.
>
> To expose a container’s internal port, an operator can start the
>   container with the -P or -p flag. The exposed port is accessible on
>   the host and the ports are available to any client that can reach the
>   host.

Read more [HERE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

Comment: Don't you mean to add --expose ?
From "docker help run", -p == --publish, which is already the first keyword argument.